# Is it possible to find deleted questions via the tools menu? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, deleted-questions

As far as I can guess, a comment on an answer that I made this morning disappeared because the parent question to which the answer (and hence my comment) was attached was deleted.  I tried to find this deleted question via the tools menu, but without success.  (The set-up of the tools menu here is somewhat different to MO, and I am more familiar with the latter.) Is it possible (for 10K+ users) to read deleted questions via the tools menu?  If so, how?

Comment: The only way I know how to find deleted posts is to go to the tools, select the "delete" tab and choose the relevant period: If you click on recently deleted, the list expands. [Direct link](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last7days). I'm pretty sure that you can't find questions deleted by their owners, though (there is at least one instance from today, but I'm sure you didn't comment there). I saw a comment of yours earlier today in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/50699/) where there is a deleted answer, but the question is still there.

Comment: @Theo: Dear Theo, Thanks, that was what I was looking for; for some reason I thought the question itself had disappearted, but obviously I just didn't look hard enough.  Best wishes,

Comment: Moderators can search for deleted question using the `deleted:1` syntax, if it is important to find a specific question you can ask a moderator to search for it. E.g. if you're discussing policy issues on meta and the question it is about has been deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ability to see all deleted posts using the tools menu seems to have been removed a few months ago for some reason.  I missed having this, but all I can do is point out this relevant feature request:

[Restore the 10k ability to see all closed/deleted posts in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list)

It now seems that we can only use the tools menu to view questions and answers that were recently deleted by someone other than the post owner (and the method to find these is given by Theo in a comment above).  One way to keep links to deleted questions is by using an RSS feed.

Comment: Dear Jonas, Thanks a lot for this.  Best wishes,

Comment: So, how do you get to the tools menu?

Comment: @Mike: With less than 10,000 reputation points, you don't.  Once you reach the threshold, the link appears at the top along with the meta/main, chat, and faq links.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Thanks for the info. I was curious as to why a certain question that was asked a few days ago cannot be found anymore, and so apparently deleted, rather than simply closed, namely, the question asking for help in proving the formula for the distance from a point to a line.

Comment: @Mike Jones: I see no question meeting that description in the list of questions recently deleted by someone other than the OP, so if it was deleted, it was probably by the OP.  You could ask a moderator.  Or perhaps it isn't deleted but just hard to find.  Is it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58969/step-in-derivation-of-distance-from-line-to-point-help-needed?

Comment: @Mike Jones: Ah, I might have found it (using Google). The question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59572/distance-between-a-point-x-1-y-1-and-a-line-ax-by-c-0 was deleted by the OP.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Thanks for the detective work. I had added a comment, and then couldn't find it in my activity list, so that got me pursuing the matter.

Comment: @Mike: For what it's worth, the question can (for now) be viewed in a Google cache at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gxh-6stVDnkJ:math.stackexchange.com/questions/59572/distance-between-a-point-x-1-y-1-and-a-line-ax-by-c-0+%22How+do+I+prove+that+the+distance+between+the+point%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com, but the cache was from before the comments were posted.  I you needed to get info from the comments, you could ask a moderator or 10k+ user.