# Can I find a deleted question if I know the identity of the poster?

Tags: support

This is related to the post [Is it possible to find deleted questions via the tools menu? If so, how?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/).

Recently, I wanted to confirm a hunch that one of the question posted by a particular user  was deleted (perhaps by him/her). I knew which user, but I no longer had a link to the question. I requested J.M. to look for a deleted question in the OP's profile page.

After some experimentation, J.M. replied that deleted questions are not listed in the profile page, even if viewed by a 10k+ rep user. We did some searching around the site afterwards, but with no success.

> **Question.** Is it possible for me to find a deleted question easily in case I know the identity of the poster? How?

*Note.* I am aware that--as a 9k user--I cannot really see deleted questions of other users. However, for the purposes of this question, assume that I am a 10k+ user, which I hope to be soon. :=)

Comment: [Pinging @JM...]

Comment: that ping won't work. @-notifications happen when you try to notify someone who is already *in* the conversation. (If you really want to ping JM, you should leave a comment on his question instead.)

Comment: Lucky for you, I read meta. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only moderators can see deleted posts in a user profile or search for them using the site search. Normal users can only use the "recently deleted" list in the 10k tools or get a link to a deleted question in any other way.

Comment: I suppose this is the definitive answer. I will wait for a day and accept it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: And the "recently deleted" list only shows posts not deleted by the OP.  There is no way to find most deleted posts using the software, anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: For recent posts one may sometimes have luck doing web searches since copies may be cached by search engines, e.g. Google. This has worked for me a few times in the past. However, I haven't tried it recently, so I don't know if any recent SE changes thwart it.